# Display Element Based on Two Custom Fields Values in BigCommerce Cornerstone Stencil Theme

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, cornerstone

I have a div I want to display on the product detail page when a given product has two custom fields that contain a particular value. For example, every product in my catalog has the following custom fields

- InventoryInStore
- InventoryOnOrder

I want to conditionally display a div element when a product's InventoryOnOrder > 0 AND it's InventoryInStore = 0.
Any help on how I can get something along the lines of the following snippet to work would be greatly appreciated!

```
{{#each custom_fields}}
    {{#if (toLowerCase name) '===' 'inventoryonorder'}}
        {{#if value '!=' 0}}
            {{#if (toLowerCase name) '===' 'inventoryinstore'}}
                {{#if value '===' 0}}
                    <div>element A</div>
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Thank you in advance for being smarter than I :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go about this wouldn't be to handle the logic and render the component in the `#each` loop. Instead, you should use the `#each` loop to iterate the keys of the `custom_fields` and check if the current iteration has the `inventoryonorder` or `inventoryinstore` name, and if it does, then you should use the `assignVar` helper to set the variable for each one and handle the logic later outside of the `#each` block.

I was able to write a working example in my Stencil environment, here's my code:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
    {{#if (toLowerCase name) "===" "inventoryonorder"}}
        {{assignVar "field_inventoryOnOrder" value}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if (toLowerCase name) "===" "inventoryinstore"}}
        {{assignVar "field_inventoryInStore" value}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}

{{#all (if (getVar "field_inventoryOnOrder") ">" "0") (if (getVar "field_inventoryInStore") "===" "0")}}
    <div>Display custom message</div>
{{/all}}
```

Notice that in the `each` loop, I don't render any content - this loop is pure handlebars and it's used to set the variables for comparison later. The `assignVar` helper is very useful if you haven't heard of it yet!

Immediately after the `each` loop handles the logic to assign the handlebars variable, I use the `#all` helper to make sure *all* of the parameters resolve true. If they do, then the content should be rendered.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Jordan. That did the trick :)

Comment: @JonMorgan Awesome! Happy to help.

Comment: A year and a half later, I'm back looking at this and once again it was the solution I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @JonMorgan Haha awesome :-) happy that I was able to help and that this is still proving useful!